# Renewenvironement error

Tags: environments, epigraphs

I'm using the epigraphs package, but try to redefine the epigraphs environment (to later on add something to it, e.g. a page break before). So I thought I do it like this:

```
\let\internepigraphs\epigraphs
\renewenvironment{epigraphs}{\begin{internepigraphs}}{\end{internepigraphs}}
```

But I get a few errors:

```
l.4 \end{epigraphs}
LaTeX Error: \begin{minipage} on input line 1 ended by \end{epigraphs}.

l.4 \end{epigraphs}                   
Missing } inserted.
```

The code runs without the definition of renewenvironment, but otherwise not. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have saved the begin code but not the end code of the original environment you need

```
\let\endinternepigraphs\endepigraphs
```

Comment: Ahhh! Thanks a lot! What a stupid mistake! I started with renewcommand and so I completely forgot about it!